# How can I mount this 250 GB external hard drive in Rasbian?

Tags: linux, mount, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a 250 GB hard drive (brand Western Digital in an Initio Corporation USB enclosure) which I would like to mount on my Raspberry Pi 3B. I have already successfully mounted the hard drive on Ubuntu 15.10 so I think it should be generally possible to do this on Linux. However it will not mount automatically so I need to do it manually.

The hard drive does show up using `lsusb` as:

```
Bus 001 Device 021: ID 13fd:160e Initio Corporation
```

The hard drive does not show up using `lsblk`.

I’m guessing I should add `udev` rules or something similar but I would need some help with the fine details if anyone has experience in mounting these types of drives.

Also, I tried connecting the USB hard drive to the Ubuntu and ran `lsusb` again. Unless I’m reading something wrong I actually got another ID here, strangely:

```
Bus 002, Device 005: ID 1058:0704 Western Digital Technologies, Inc My Passport Essential  (WDME)
```

Comment: I think on Ubuntu it's automatically listed in the file manager (Nautilus) and mounted with the click of a button. That's not the case on Raspbian but I still think there should be a way to do it manually.

Comment: I would prefer testing to mount it manually first in any way possible before I rush out to buy another gadget as I already have too much stuff.

Comment: If you want to use bus-powered high-draw USB devices like hard drives with your Raspberry Pi, connect them to a powered USB hub instead of directly to the Pi. Especially with the Pi 3.